# Performance testing using jmeter scripts

Tags: jmeter

When I have my settings of the script as below

Concurrency : 1
hold-for: 0s
ramp-up: 1s
throughput: 10
iterations: 100

What does it mean

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency and Hold Load For related to the [Concurrency Thread Group Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/).

[Ramp-up](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) means is the time JMeter will take to start all concurrent requests: If you setup 100 requests and ramp-up of 10 seconds, JMeter will start 10 requests per second, on average.
Throughput is the amount of requests completed by per second, shown e.g. on an [Aggregate Report](https://jmetervn.com/2016/10/10/analyze-the-aggregate-report-in-jmeter/).
Iterations is the number of times a Thread Group will be executed. E.g., if the example above of 100 requests have 5 iterations, a total of 500 requests will be sent.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I am slightly confused with the different between ramp up and hold for

Comment: Hold Load For "overrides" iteration. If you determine X seconds to Hold Load, JMeter will continually hit the endpoint for X seconds, no matter how many requests is sent. Ramp-up determines only the cadence of requests in each individual iteration - when an iteration ends, it starts "counting" again.